# Create CIImage with same image scale?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have UIImage with object like this

```
<UIImage: 0x17428b540> size {937.5, 1250} orientation 0 scale 2.000000
```

I want to create CIIImage.

```
CIImage* ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage options:nil];
```

Its output like this :

```
<CIImage: 0x174c003b0 extent [0 0 1875 2500]>
```

You can see size of CIImage is double as of size of UIImage. How can I get CIImage with same scale (size) of UIImage?

Comment: CIImage is taking points of that image not pixels, So its printing point of that image. I think ....

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

`CIImage` and `CGImage` have no scale. Only when you convert them to `UIImage` you set a scale.

For example, to create a `UIImage` from `CGImage` with a scale, use:

```
let image = UIImage(cgImage: your_cgImage, scale: your_scale, orientation: your_orientation)
```

(Swift 4)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
UIImage *image = YOUR_IMAGE;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
CGImageRef imgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect); // It returns CIImage only and size will be same.
```